# Junit (DBUnit) tests fail with Maven but not in Eclipse?

Tags: junit, dbunit, maven-surefire-plugin

My Junit tests use DBUnit and they run fine when run from Eclipse. However, running the same tests with Maven fails one test with:

```
integrity constraint violation: foreign key no action
```

I have tried running that test and the entire set of tests from eclipse GUI ("run as JUnit test") several times in a row and they never fail - but from Maven they do fail.

I use @DatabaseSetup for each test, but is it enough to really reset the database? I also thought Maven might run the tests in parallel so I tried setting forkMode to "always" for Surefire plugin in my pom.xml, but it didn't change anything.

Comment: Did you try to [run a single test with maven](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/single-test.html) ?

Comment: Good point. Now that I've tried, running the test class of the failing test separately passes, but running all tests fails as mentioned.

Comment: But running "entire set of tests from eclipse GUI" works ? This is weird. Are you sure, this is the same set of tests ?

Comment: It should be. It's a standard maven project with standard directory structure.

Comment: I am not a DBUnit expert. Your are using @DatabaseSetUp but not the  [@DatabaseTearDown](http://springtestdbunit.github.com/spring-test-dbunit/apidocs/com/github/springtestdbunit/annotation/DatabaseTearDown.html) ?

Comment: I thought I already tried that, but apparently I didn't - that solved it! Thanks! Please answer this question instead of comment so I can credit you for the answer!

Comment: Ok, i did it but i still don't understand why it works in eclipse ?!

Comment: neither do I, but I'm glad it works with teardown added. It could have something to do with Maven running the tests in parallel, thus having multiple instances of the memory database going at the same time. Not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your are using the annotation `@DatabaseSetUp` from [spring-test DBUnit](http://springtestdbunit.github.com/spring-test-dbunit/) for the database initialization. You should use the annotation `@DatabaseTearDown` too.

From the [spring-test DBUnit](http://springtestdbunit.github.com/spring-test-dbunit/) documentation :

*`The @DatabaseTearDown annotation can be used to reset database tables once a test has completed. As with @DatabaseSetup the annotation can be applied at the method or class level. When using @DatabaseTearDown use the value and type attributes in the same way as @DatabaseSetup.`*

Comment: Is there a way to create entirely new schema on every case? @DatabaseTearDown is not able to reset id generators and in some of my tests i checking ids in expected dataset.

Comment: @stanislav.chetvertkov I don't know. You could ask another question.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar Problem refering to encoding used in the JVM during the maven tests.

I added following to my pom.xml:

```
<plugins>
    ...
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <junitArtifactName>junit:junit</junitArtifactName>
            <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
            <inputEncoding>UTF-8</inputEncoding>
            <outputEncoding>UTF-8</outputEncoding>
            <argLine>-Xms256m -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=128m -ea
                -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8</argLine>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

See also herer http://carlobertoldi.wordpress.com/2012/03/12/maven-unit-tests-and-those-funny-characters/

This solved my problems

Comment: Is this answer related to the question ?